# Why doesn't onMarkerReached get called in the next play unless I leave enough time after stopping?

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, callback, audiotrack

(Sorry to fix it over and over.)

I want to play a new stream immediately after stopping AudioTrack.

However, if you do not start playback after a few milliseconds after stopping playback with **stop ()**, **OnMarkerReached** callback may not be called.

I wrote sample code.

Press the button to play the sound.

When the button is pressed, data for 0.5 seconds is written to AudioTrack, and after 0.25 seconds, the waveform for the next 0.5 seconds is written to AudioTrack by **onMarkerReached**. The sound played is 2 seconds sound.

If you press the button while playing the sound for 2 seconds, it will **stop ()**, **flush ()** and start the next playback. At this time, **OnMarkerReached** may not be called unless an extra time is inserted before playback.

Verification was performed on two android devices.

**OnMarkerReached** was called even if device A had 0 seconds of the extra time.
However, **OnMarkerReached** was not called even if device B had 10ms extra time.

Why does **onMarkerReached** sometimes not be called?

Here is the sample code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.audiotrackexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener {

    final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    Button playBtn;
    Button queryBtn;
    TextView curPosTv;
    TextView curPosTv2;

    public class SinGenerator {

        float freq;
        int samplingRate;
        int sampleCount;

        public SinGenerator(float freq, int samplingRate){
            this.freq = freq;
            this.samplingRate = samplingRate;
            this.sampleCount = 0;
        }

        public short generate(){
            this.sampleCount++;
            double t = (double)freq * sampleCount / samplingRate;
            double sin = Math.sin(2.0 * Math.PI * t);
            return (short) (sin*Short.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 16000;
    static final int AUDIO_DATA_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    static final int CHANNEL = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
    static final int READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE = SAMPLING_RATE / 2;    // 0.5s
    static final int AUDIO_TRACK_MIN_BUFFER_SIZE = SAMPLING_RATE;
    int audioTrackBufferSize;
    AudioTrack audioTrack;
    SinGenerator sinGenerator = new SinGenerator(300, SAMPLING_RATE);
    short[] wave;
    short[] readWaveBuff = new short[READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int waveReadLen = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());

    void setNextWave(){
        System.arraycopy( wave, waveReadLen, readWaveBuff, 0, READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE );
        waveReadLen += READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playBtn = findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        queryBtn = findViewById(R.id.queryBtn);
        curPosTv = findViewById(R.id.curPosTv);
        curPosTv2 = findViewById(R.id.curPosTv2);

        queryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "curPlaybackPos : " + audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition());
                curPosTv2.setText("curPlaybackPos : " + audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition());
            }
        });

        audioTrackBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
                SAMPLING_RATE,
                CHANNEL,
                AUDIO_DATA_FORMAT);

        if (audioTrackBufferSize < AUDIO_TRACK_MIN_BUFFER_SIZE) {
            audioTrackBufferSize = AUDIO_TRACK_MIN_BUFFER_SIZE;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "audioTrackBufferSize : " + audioTrackBufferSize);

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
              AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
              SAMPLING_RATE,
              CHANNEL,
              AUDIO_DATA_FORMAT,
              audioTrackBufferSize,
              AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(MainActivity.this);

        wave = new short[READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE * 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            sinGenerator = new SinGenerator(300 + i * 100, SAMPLING_RATE);
            for (int j = 0; j < READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE; j++) {
                wave[i * READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE + j] = sinGenerator.generate();
            }
        }

        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                audioTrack.stop();
                audioTrack.flush();

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        waveReadLen = 0;
                        setNextWave();

                        audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE / 2);
                        audioTrack.write(readWaveBuff, 0, READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE);
                        audioTrack.play();
                        curPosTv.setText("curPlaybackPos : " + audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition());
                    }
                },0);        // device A is onMarkerReached called. but device B is not.
//                }, 10);        // device A is onMarkerReached called. but device B is not.
//                }, 100);     // Devices A and B call onMarkerReached.

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track) {

        curPosTv.setText("curPlaybackPos : " + audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition());
        if(waveReadLen == wave.length) {
            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.flush();
            Log.d(TAG, "finish playing");
        } else {

            setNextWave();
            audioTrack.write(readWaveBuff, 0, READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE);
            int newMarkerPosition = audioTrack.getNotificationMarkerPosition();
            if (waveReadLen == wave.length) {
                newMarkerPosition += (READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE / 2) + READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE;
            } else {
                newMarkerPosition += READ_WAVE_BUFFER_SIZE;
            }

            audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(newMarkerPosition);
            Log.d(TAG, "curPos : " + audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition() + " markerPos : " + audioTrack.getNotificationMarkerPosition());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track) {
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Audio Play">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/curPosTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/queryBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Query marker position">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/curPosTv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.audiotrackexample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: We decided to imitate ExoPlayer and recreate AudioTrack every time. Thanks for seeing the question and answering it.

Answer (score 0):

`onMarkerReached` is a pretty poorly-specified API; behavior appears to change from OEM to OEM, and from what I've seen, update intervals can be as large as a second (just as coarse as the return values from `AudioTrack.getNotificationMarkerPosition()`). IMHO, the only acceptable use case for `onMarkerReached()` is periodic seekbar updates for a mediaplayer-type control.

It's a much better idea to just stream your new content into a single, pre-existing `AudioTrack`. In other words, you just start one `AudioTrack`, leave it playing, and make sure it never starves (you can insert silence into the track to fill any gaps). That way, you get to decide how "playback 1" transitions into "playback2", and you have precise control over the timing.

Comment: Thank you for providing your valuable feedback and solutions. I never came up with a way to keep playing. By the way, where do you find it to be a fairly poorly specified API?

Comment: "never came up"? I answered this 48 minutes ago!  :)  I said it was poorly specified b/c the documentation does not specify an update interval, and my own testing has shown that it varies widely from device to device.

Comment: It's okay because I understand the idea to keep playing.
I understand that the update is rough.
Is "update" when OnMarkerReached is called?
However, this time, OnMarkerReached is not called even though the marker was set before the second playback. The timing is rough, but isn't it a bug that isn't called OnMarkerReached?
I am not good at English, so you may not understand that you have already provided the answer.

Comment: Right, by "update interval" I mean the rate at which `onMarkerReached()` is called.

Comment: I am not sure why your delay choices would have an effect on `onMarkerReached()`. It seems to me that your delay of 0/10/100 simply changes the delay between the button press, and the start of playback. I am surprised that makes a difference. I am also surprised you don't get an `IllegalStateException` the first time you call `AudioTrack.stop()`...

Comment: By the way, you should use `postDelayed()`; that makes your `ScheduledExecutorService` unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The code was modified.
Also, I noticed that when onMarkerReached was not called during the second play, I checked the playbackPosition and found that it stopped at 2000-4000. In other words, the play itself seems to stop.

Comment: Note that `stop()`-ing and `flush()`-ing is gonna return the playback head position to 0. It does not last for the lifetime of the `AudioTrack`; only the lifetime of the current play (as the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getPlaybackHeadPosition()) specify).